# How to align the beginning of the citations in the footnote?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I have the problem that in my foot citations there is an extra space character between the Cf. and the name of the first author. If subsequent cites are different it does not have any impact, but with the *ibid* there is an offset.

I was already able to identify the piece of code of the *Footnote Settings* that's causing this. If I comment out

```
\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}
```

everything is aligned and fine. The problem is that I need this code resp. it's result, so I can't just delete it. I also tried to add a blank space in front of *andothers*, but naturally it is running in an error. (BTW: I did not write this command myself.)

Whether it can be fixed by deleting the space in front of the author name or by adding one in front of the ibid doesn't matter. I am happy with any solution.

Here the MWE:

```
 %Meta-Informationen %
 \documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

%Bibliography & Citation %
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex} \addbibresource{Minimalbeispiel1.bib}

%Footnote Settings%
 \DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

%%%%END PREAMBLE%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    Example A.\footnote{\cite[Cf.][1]{Adler1899}.}
    Example B.\footnote{\cite[Cf.][2]{Adler1899}.}
    \end{document}
```

And here the Bib entry:

```
@BOOK{Adler1899,
year = {1899},
author = {Adler}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unintentionally introducing the unwanted space yourself.  Try instead:

```
%Footnote Settings%
 \DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{% <-- Note the trailing '%'
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}% <-- and here
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Comment: You probably also want to add a `%` after the second line (compare the standard definition of `initsonly` in `biblatex.def`). It could be though, that the space introduced there is compensated by following commands and their use of `\unspace` and the like.

Comment: @moewe -- Good point. Certainly doesn't hurt....